# how to refresh an iframe automatically

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I would like an iframe to refresh itself to the source path specified.  What is the easiest way to do this inline with javascript?

thanks,

Comment: note:  it must be done constantly, like lets say on 2 or 3 seconds interval continuously.

Answer (score 15):

If you're also perhaps looking for a way of doing this without javascript enabled, and have access to modify the iframe HTML, then you could add this reload code to the `<head>` tag of the iframe HTML:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="600">
```

Answer (score 10):

You can use setInterval(function, milliseconds, param1, param2, ...)

Something like this:

```
var frameRefreshInterval = setInterval(function() {
    document.getElementById("myframe").src = document.getElementById("myframe").src
}, 2000);
```

The interval resets the iframe's `src` attribute ever 2 seconds (2000 milliseconds)

**Edit, to answer you comments:**
This, along with any other code that manipulates the DOM, should be in a `window.onload` event listener or similar like so:

```
<script type=text/javascript>
window.onload = function() {
    var frameRefreshInterval = setInterval(function() {
        document.getElementById("myframe").src = document.getElementById("myframe").src
    }, 2000);
    // any other code
}
</script>
```

Comment: this does not seem to be working, I just included the script at the top of my page and set the id equal to that of the iframe i'm specifying.  Its not refreshing though.  I tested it with ctrl+R after about 10 seconds and only then it refreshes.

Comment: @triq, is it wrapped in a `window.onload` event listener or similar? If not, the code is looking for an iframe that hasn't loaded yet.

Comment: so would i just include this at the top of my page?

Comment: can you give an example of how to write this up at the top of the page starting with the <script type=text/javascript> tag

Comment: btw my source is an inline embedded php command, dont know if that affects it

Comment: @triq you need to replace `myframe` with the `id` attribute you have given your frame

Comment: yea i understand that, i replaced it with my specific id

Comment: <IFRAME src="<?php echo site_url();?>/information" name="iframe2" id="informationiframe" style="height:370px; width:1235px">

</IFRAME>

Comment: @triq i need the javascript too, please edit your original question to include that. Don't paste it in the comments, they aren't intended for it.

Answer (score 4):

```
setInterval(function(){
    document.getElementById("myframe").src+="";
},2500);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
function refresh()
{
    var iframe = document.getElementById('iframe');
    iframe.reload(true);
}

setTimeout('refresh()', 3000);
```

Note, this will try to refresh the page every 3 seconds. Obviously, if the page takes a while to load, i.e. over 3 seconds then you wont see anything.

Hope this helps.

Comment: There will be no noticeable difference between using setTimeout and setInterval.

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
<script>
     window.setInterval("reloadIFrame();", 3000);

     function reloadIFrame()
     {
          document.frames["frameNameHere"].location.reload();
     }
</script>
```

Interval Time Is 3 Second.

Comment: Where should we put this script?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to refresh an iframe itself.

```
document.getElementById('iframe');//this may not work
```

and you can try this.

```
window.frameElement.src = window.frameElement.src
```