# how to refresh an iframe in php page

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to refresh an iframe automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6975765/how-to-refresh-an-iframe-automatically)

I need to refresh an iframe on a php page from its source, which is given by

```
src = "<?php echo site_url();?>/information"
```

I want this to be done often, let's say every 1 or 2 seconds.

Looking for a way to do this in JavaScript that I can search for the id of the iframe and refresh it.

Comment: php can't help here. retagged

Comment: Why are you asking the same question 2 times?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var timer;
    function refreshIframe(){
    if(timer)
    clearInterval(timer)
    timer = setTimeout(refreshIframe,5000)
    var iframe = document.getElementById('iframe'); 
    iframe.src='http://google.com';
    }

    refreshIframe();
</script>
<iframe id="iframe" src="http://google.com" width="100%" height="300">
  <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/GqvZS/3/

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for a way of doing this without javascript enabled, and have access to modify the iframe HTML, then you could add this reload code to the `<head>` tag of the iframe HTML:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="600">
```

Answer (score 1):

Javascript way:

```
 setInterval(refreshIframe,1000);

 function refreshIframe() {
    window.frames["myframe"].src = window.frame["myframe"].src;
 } 

 <iframe src="/information" name='myframe' id='myframe'></iframe>
```

Meta tag way:

```
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1" />
```