# Chrome Extension Javascript/jQuery load page and check if changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, iframe, google-chrome-extension

I'm looking for a way to load a website and then check after 1 min or so whether the content has changed, if not, repeat. This is because the website I'm trying to get content from contains javascript for loading the div I need. I thought of using some kind of iFrame, but I have no idea where to start and Google isn't helping me.

**Edit**

This is the code I'm running with atm and scrapUrl is a defined url so don't worry about it:

```
var iframe = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('iframe'));
iframe.src = scrapUrl;
$(iframe).ready(function() {
    $(iframe).load(function() {
        alert('loaded');
        alert($(iframe).contents().find('div#description').html());
    });
});
```

It outputs "loaded" and after that "undefined"

Comment: So you want an iFrame that reloads every so often? And you can't find that [on Google](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=automatically+reloading+iframe)? What about this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6975765/how-to-refresh-an-iframe-automatically

Comment: use javascript setinterval() method

Comment: It's an iFrame object, not an actual iFrame on the page.

Answer (score 0):

So you're doing a lazy load of content in a div, and you want to know when that div has loaded?  Depending how you're doing it, you'd be better to set a flag and react to the AJAX "load" event associated with that lazy load.

If you must do it the way you suggest, try this:

1. Create an interval (setInterval) that checks the load status, or the contents of the div
2. if false, do nothing.  If true, clearInterval.

Comment: No, I'm actually working on a Chrome extension. The page I'm loading has a link that appears after a period of time which is always different. I need to get that link from that page, when I get it using AJAX, the link will be undefined since the javascript on the page hasn't finished showing the link. I have added the code that I have atm.

Comment: Oh I see.  I'm not familiar with this area.  Typically you'd wait for onload or ready but if the content is coming in dynamically, those may not be accurate for what you want.  I'm sure you know that though :)

Comment: I still haven't found the answer to my problem.